# Is there a way to use my smart phone as a second screen of my laptop?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, android

About ten years ago everyone at work started using dual monitors. It was great. But I switched to laptop for most tasks and do not have a second monitor. It occurred to me that I have a second screen right next to me (my phone) that I'm not using.

Is it possible to use it as a second monitor? I can imagine using it to show a training video while I follow along on the main screen.

I have a Mac and my phone is Android Galaxy 6S. I have an older iPhone 4S as well. Funnibly enough, my Android phone has higher resolution than my Macbook.

Comment: If you are willing to download programs on both your phone and your laptop, yes; I just don't know off the top of my head what

Comment: You should be able to use AirPlay to stream from one Apple device to another or Kodi (XBMC). As Mac is not something that i'm good with i'll suggest another variant.
 * Using Spaces virtual desktops and VNC to view virtual desktop on your phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you won't accept streaming as an option. In that case you can use 3rd party software such as [AirDuet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=superle.airduetscreen), [AirDisplay2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avatron.airdisplay2), [iDisplay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idisplay.virtualscreen), [SplashTop Extended Display](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splashtop.xdisplay.wired.free) or [Splashtop Extended Display HD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splashtop.remote.xdisplay). These require you to install apps on your phone and PC. After installation you can use USB or WiFi to connect your phone as a 2nd screen.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying one of them now. FYI The reviews for almost all of them are all over the place; mainly, it doesn't work at all or it works. There's probably a valid reason (no USB host support).

Comment: @1.21gigawatts (& Mustafa): I voted to approve your edit because this is a response to your own question.  However, just a link, or list of product links, isn't generally considered a useful answer for the site because it doesn't add value to a simple Google search.  A software recommendation should include some basic information on why you're recommending it and even better, how to use it to solve the problem.  Good guidance on recommending software [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).

Comment: I think it's fine with just links. I can follow the link to find more information